# Difference between &foo->bar and foo->bar

Tags: c, pointers, struct, operator-precedence

I know that `foo->bar` means `(*foo).bar` and it gets the member called bar from the struct that foo points to but I can't understand what `&foo->bar` means and what is the purpose of it.

Comment: It gives you the address of `bar`. It means `&(foo->bar)`, NOT `(&foo)->bar`

Comment: I recommend reading [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then looking into [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Also read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). With GCC, compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` -all warnings and debug info. Look also (for inspiration) into existing C code on https://github.com/ and use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: Note that if `foo->bar` is an array, then `foo->bar` and `&foo->bar` may be equivalent, depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

Operator `->` has higher precedence than the operator `&`, so `&foo->bar = &(foo->bar)`. Check the below code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct  
{
    int boo;
}Foo;

int main()
{
    Foo * foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    foo->boo = 5;

    printf("The value of boo is %d\n", foo->boo);
    printf("The addredd of boo is %p\n",&foo->boo);
    printf("The addredd of boo is %p\n",&(foo->boo));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
The value of boo is 5
The addredd of boo is 0x55b3c43e5260
The addredd of boo is 0x55b3c43e5260
```

From, this you can conclude that `&foo->boo` is same as `&(foo->boo)`.
`&foo->boo` is the address of `foo->boo`

Comment: And if i want to store a number in boo i store it in foo->boo.Right? Not in &foo->boo?

Comment: Yes,  `foo->boo = 5;` .   `&foo->boo`  is address of `foo->boo`

Comment: @XarisXaris Note : Operator `->` has higher precedence than the operator `&` . So `&foo->bar = &(foo->bar)`